# Using Data Mapper in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I follow up below document for using Data Mapper in WSO2 ESB:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Using+Data+Mapper+Mediator+in+WSO2+ESB

When I tried to run the application using the server in WSO2 Developer Studio ESB Tool, the application is deployed.

But when I tried to create `.car` file (CompositeApplication -> right click on pom.xml -> Export Configuration), I get below window:

[image]

And I filled required fields and clicked on 'Finished'. Finally I checked on the "Export location" whether the file is created. But in the location, no file created. Please give proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the car file, you should right click on your composite application project and choose Export Composite Application Project. According to the screenshot you are triggering some other Visual Data Mapper exporter.